# Non-singlet and singlet flavor combination

Tags: terminology, group-theory, group-representations, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

In the perturbative QCD, specific partonic distribution functions (pdf) linear combination is called "flavor singlet" or "flavor nonsinglet" combination.

What is the combination, and why are they called flavor "singlet" or "non-singlet" combination? Does evolution equation (DGLAP equation) of these specific linear combination of pdf functions take a particular form?

Comment: This answer - http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269380/  - might be useful. The only difference is that the algebra now is $su(3)$ and this algebra does not have n-dimensional representations for any integer $n$. I remember it has for $n=1,3,6,8,10,...$. The singlet is the one dimensional representation, i.e., the transformation is trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly means "is a singlet under $SU(N)$"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86282/)

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/2451